# Xamarin get GPS location in the background service

Tags: android, xamarin, gps

I am building an app which retrieves location data from the device when its running as background service and when its connected to the server it would send the gps data. The problem is everything is working when the app is open and when I close the app all the process stops working but the app is still running in the background.

I have used source code from this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_android_backgrounding_walkthrough/

And I have only made some changes in the "LocationService.cs" file. Below is the "LocationService.cs" code. I am using this for testing purposes.

```
[Service]
public class LocationService : Service, ILocationListener
{
    public event EventHandler<LocationChangedEventArgs> LocationChanged = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<ProviderDisabledEventArgs> ProviderDisabled = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<ProviderEnabledEventArgs> ProviderEnabled = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged = delegate { };

    List<GpsList> _gpsList = new List<GpsList>();
    public Location lastLocation;

    // Set our location manager as the system location service
    protected LocationManager LocMgr = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService("location") as LocationManager;

    readonly string logTag = "LocationService";
    IBinder binder;

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Log.Debug(logTag, "OnCreate called in the Location Service");
    }

    // This gets called when StartService is called in our App class
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(logTag, "LocationService started");
        // start a task here
        new Task(() => {

        }).Start();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    // This gets called once, the first time any client bind to the Service
    // and returns an instance of the LocationServiceBinder. All future clients will
    // reuse the same instance of the binder
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug(logTag, "Client now bound to service");

        binder = new LocationServiceBinder(this);
        return binder;
    }

    // Handle location updates from the location manager
    public void StartLocationUpdates()
    {
        var locationCriteria = new Criteria();

        locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement;
        locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.NoRequirement;

        // get provider: GPS, Network, etc.
        var locationProvider = LocMgr.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);
        Log.Debug(logTag, string.Format("You are about to get location updates via {0}", locationProvider));

        //GET Last Location
        lastLocation = LocMgr.GetLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

        // Get an initial fix on location
        LocMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 3000, 0, this);

        Log.Debug(logTag, "Now sending location updates");
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        Log.Debug(logTag, "Service has been terminated");
    }

    List<double> distanceList = new List<double>();
    public void OnLocationChanged(Android.Locations.Location location)
    {
        this.LocationChanged(this, new LocationChangedEventArgs(location));
        var distance = location.DistanceTo(lastLocation);

        if (distanceList.Contains(distance) != true)
        {
            distanceList.Add(distance);
        }


        if (distanceList.Count >= 2)
        {
            var latestDistance = distanceList[0] - distanceList[1];
            Log.Debug(logTag, "LatestDistance " + latestDistance);
            distanceList.Clear();

            _gpsList.Add(new GpsList()
            {
                Distance = latestDistance,
                Latitude = location.Latitude,
                Longitude = location.Longitude,
                Altitude = location.Altitude,
                Speed = location.Speed,
                Heading = location.Bearing,
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd"),
                Time = location.Time.ToString(),
                Valid = true
            });

        }


        Log.Debug(logTag, "Bearing " + location.Bearing);
        Log.Debug(logTag, "Distance " + location.DistanceTo(lastLocation));

        string dbPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(dbPath, "TrackOne.db"));
        db.CreateTable<GpsLogData>();

        //FOR FILITERING
        if (_gpsList.Count >= 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in _gpsList)
            {
                var logData = new GpsLogData
                {
                    Latitude = item.Latitude,
                    Longitude = item.Longitude,
                    Altitude = item.Altitude,
                    Speed = item.Speed,
                    Heading = item.Heading,
                    Date = item.Date,
                    Time = item.Time,
                    Valid = item.Valid
                };

                db.Insert(logData);
            }

            _gpsList.Clear();

        }

        //CHECK FOR INTERNET
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
        NetworkInfo activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
        bool isOnline = (activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected;

        if (db.Table<GpsLogData>().Count() != 0 && isOnline)
        {
            var table = db.Table<GpsLogData>();

            foreach (var item in table)
            {
                Log.Debug(logTag, "SEND STRING " + item.Id);

                SendGpsString();

                db.Delete<GpsLogData>(item.Id);
                Log.Debug(logTag, "DELETE RECORD " + item.Id);
            }
        }

    }

    public void SendGpsString()
    {
        //TCP SOCKET
        try
        {
            string textToSend = "sample data";

            //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2", 8888);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            //Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text---
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            //Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
            //Console.ReadLine();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Info("TrackerX", ex.Message);
        }
        //END TCP SOCKET
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
        this.ProviderDisabled(this, new ProviderDisabledEventArgs(provider));
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
        this.ProviderEnabled(this, new ProviderEnabledEventArgs(provider));
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
        this.StatusChanged(this, new StatusChangedEventArgs(provider, status, extras));
    }

}

public class GpsLogData
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Altitude { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public double Heading { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
public class GpsList
{
    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Altitude { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public double Heading { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you define what you do when you "close" the application? Are you force closing the application or simply hitting the Android "Home" button or switching applications via the Task Manager? You might be force killing any services associated with your application which is why the functionality stops.

Comment: i am closing the app via the Task Manager.

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix for this? I'm using the same example project, and out of the box it doesn't work in the background - despite saying that it should.

Comment: Yeah, use this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63170/getting-gps-location-data-in-the-background-service